Is there a way to remove the background color on page navigation link without removing it from slideshow widget?
I have attached a screenshot that explains better what I'm trying to achieve. I am having trouble figuring out how to remove the background color that is showing up on my website page navigation link, without the background color disappearing from the dots that go with the slideshow on my page. Is there some extra code I can add to differentiate the two?
This is the section of code that is the problem:
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

Here is the complete code I am using for the slideshow:


let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 570px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: #444444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/bags/bag_1080x1080_01.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/bags/bag_1080x1080_02.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/bags/bag_1080x1080_03.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/bags/bag_1080x1080_04.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/bags/bag_1080x1080_05.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/bags/bag_1080x1080_06.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/bags/bag_1080x1080_07.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span> 
</div>



My knowledge of how to manipulate the code is limited so other than removing the line of code that is the problem, I've not been able to figure it out.
Screenshot of problem

Define a scope to limit the reach of your rules. The ".active" class is common, so it might conflict with other elements on the site.
For example:
.slideshow-container .dot.active, .slideshow-container .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

Some tips:

Use more specific classes to target elements. For example, use
.nav-link.active for navigation links and .dot.active for slideshow
dots.
Consider using naming conventions like BEM (Block Element Modifier)
to organize your classes. For instance, use .slideshow__dot--active.
Make sure the classes you create are used in a
specific way to avoid conflicts.


Thank you, the code you suggested took away the dark background of the navigation link, but it's also taken away the "dark dot" for the current image in the slideshow. Now they're all the same color grey. I am not well-versed enough in coding to know how to implement the tips you suggested, would you be able to show me what the code would be for the dark dot to still be there?
(Edited for typos)

I answered generally without noticing that the class slideshow-container did not include all the elements of your slider, especially the dots. So in the following code, I wrapped everything in a new class called slideshow. As you can see in the code, I made sure to contain the scope of all rules to slideshow, thus reducing the risk of conflicts
https://jsfiddle.net/SaoudiH/u9bpryzo/20/
